# Nancy route - return value on callback

Tags: c#, asynchronous, event-handling, .net-4.5, nancy

I have an application which is controlled remotely. The program has to play animation on request and response to the client when it was finished. This is the code I have now (and it works not properly):

```
public void PlayAnimation(Action callback)
{
    DoubleAnimation fadeOut = new DoubleAnimation
    {
        //settings
    };
    fadeOut.Completed += (s, e) => callback();
    BeginAnimation(OpacityProperty, fadeOut);
}


Get["/playAnim/{id}"] = param =>
{
    MainWindow.PlayAnimation(() => {/* Need to call "return" statement here */});
    return "Ok"; // This is where the value is returned now.
    //The execution gets here before animation was completed.
};
```

I know, Nancy also supports `async-await` syntax, but `DoubleAnimation` doesn't (or it does?). So, how do I make Nancy respond *after* the animation was played?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you told by your own - Nancy supports async methods, so here you can use [TaskCompletionSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd449174%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). Second part of your code will look like this:

```
Get["/playAnim/{id}"] = async param =>
{
    var completionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    MainWindow.PlayAnimation(() => { completionSource.SetResult(true); });

    await completionSource.Task;

    return "Ok"; 
};
```